# How to throw 404 error correctly using Django + Apache via FastCGI

Tags: django, apache

I use Django with Apache via FastCGI. When I throw 404 error from django (for example, get_or_404 method) there is a correct page displayed, but server return code is 200, not 404.
How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: hmm - the get_object_or_404() should raise Http404 exception.. Are you sure that you're getting? Try rising django.http.Http404 exception manually in the view and then check HTTP error code on your server.

Comment: I think we need to see some apache access logs which you are sure should be 404 response codes.